# Does SQL Service need restart after NW adapter teaming?

Tags: sql-server

Recently we discovered in our AlwaysOn cluster, one node was using one NIC as stand-by in team of two NICs. While on another node it was using both NICs actively. We got first one changed to active as same as other node.

My question is - Do we need to restart SQL services or server itself for these changes to take effect from SQL perspective (like in AG sync)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is - Do we need to restart SQL services or server itself for these changes to take effect from SQL perspective (like in AG sync)?

You shouldn't, no, since they aren't presented as two different interfaces. This should be taken care of by the driver for the adaptors - do whatever its documentation states. SQL calls into winsock and the OS handles it from there.